# Sort by value based on another column value with self joins

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have asked this question before, but now need to add more fields and the same method is now timing out because of too many self joins.

This is my current query.  It is slow, but performant enough when I add the city and state columns, but when I add the zip column it times out.  Is there another method of doing this?

```
SELECT um.user_id, 
       users.display_name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(um.meta_value SEPARATOR ' '),
       city.meta_value,
       state.meta_value,
       zip.meta_value
FROM `wp_7bv88z_usermeta` um, 
     `wp_7bv88z_pmpro_memberships_users` u, 
     `wp_7bv88z_users` users,
     `wp_7bv88z_usermeta` lname,
     `wp_7bv88z_usermeta` fname,
     `wp_7bv88z_usermeta` city,
     `wp_7bv88z_usermeta` state,
     `wp_7bv88z_usermeta` zip
WHERE u.user_id = um.user_id 
     and users.id = u.user_id 
     and (lname.user_id = u.user_id and lname.meta_key = 'pmpro_slastname')
     and (fname.user_id = u.user_id and fname.meta_key = 'pmpro_sfirstname')
     and (city.user_id = u.user_id and city.meta_key = 'pmpro_scity')
     and (state.user_id = u.user_id and state.meta_key = 'pmpro_sstate')
     and (zip.user_id = u.user_id and zip.meta_key = 'pmpro_szipcode')
     and (um.meta_key='pmpro_sfirstname' or um.meta_key='pmpro_slastname') 
     and u.status='active'
GROUP BY lname.meta_value, fname.meta_value, city.meta_value, 
         state.meta_value, zip.meta_value, um.user_id
```

Sample Data:

user_meta table

```
╔════=====╦══════════════==╦══════=======╗
║ user_id ║  meta_key        ║ meta_value  ║
╠════=====╬══════════════==╬══════=======╣
║  1      ║ pmpro_sfirstname ║ Jeff        ║
║  1      ║ pmpro_slasttname ║ Atwood      ║
║  1      ║ pmpro_scity      ║ Chicago     ║
║  1      ║ pmpro_sstate     ║ IL          ║
║  1      ║ pmpro_szip       ║ 60007       ║
║  2      ║ pmpro_sfirstname ║ Geoff       ║
║  2      ║ pmpro_slasttname ║ Davis       ║
║  2      ║ pmpro_scity      ║ Fairfax     ║
║  2      ║ pmpro_sstate     ║ VA          ║
║  2      ║ pmpro_szip       ║ 22030       ║
║  3      ║ pmpro_sfirstname ║ Jarrod      ║
║  3      ║ pmpro_slasttname ║ Minor       ║
║  3      ║ pmpro_scity      ║ Dallas      ║
║  3      ║ pmpro_sstate     ║ TX          ║
║  3      ║ pmpro_szip       ║ 75001       ║
║  4      ║ pmpro_sfirstname ║ Joel        ║
║  4      ║ pmpro_slasttname ║ Brown       ║
║  4      ║ pmpro_scity      ║ Boston      ║
║  4      ║ pmpro_sstate     ║ MA          ║
║  4      ║ pmpro_szip       ║ 02101       ║
╚════=====╩════════════=====╩══════======╝
```

Expected Results:

```
1, Jeff Atwood, Chicago, IL, 60007
4, Joel Brown, Fairfax, VA, 22030
2, Geoff Davis, Dallas, TX, 75001
3, Jarrod Minor, Boston, MA, 02101
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on the tables and how is the execution plan looking?

Comment: I am not the admin of the database and do not have permission to add indexes.  None of the existing indexes are on the columns I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation to pick values from EAV data stucture

```
select  user_id,
        max( case when meta_key = 'pmpro_sfirstname' then meta_value else null end) fname,
        max( case when meta_key = 'pmpro_slasttname' then meta_value else null end) lname,
        max( case when meta_key = 'pmpro_scity' then meta_value else null end) city,
        max( case when meta_key = 'pmpro_sstate' then meta_value else null end) state,
        max( case when meta_key = 'pmpro_szip' then meta_value else null end) zip
from user_meta
group by user_id
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad939/4)

Comment: This works for the one table.  I had only included sample data for that one, but there are actually 3 joins in the original query.  I am getting a bunch of rows that are NULL even if the status is active.

Comment: @Ci-CiMillsThomson can you ask a new question by posting your original query with joins and also include sample data for your tables that would be helpful, this answer is specific to your query in question